# Read only links for questions linked for meta

Tags: feature-request, meta, hyperlinks

I'm going to keep this short, since I believe we've all seen this so:

- People come here and complain about their question/answer/goat, or another's question/answer/goat
- That suddenly gets the said question/answer/goat a flurry of votes.
- Which in turn both skews the natural flow of events and makes discussion and context hard.

Can we please default to read only links for questions/answers that are linked to from meta discussions?

Comment: For those unfamiliar [this is a goat](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Hausziege_04.jpg/384px-Hausziege_04.jpg) (image CC Kuebi Wikipedia)

Comment: That is a nice goat. I like that goat.

Comment: @RUJordan new gravatar? :)

Comment: @bluefeet nooooo rlemon might punt me out of the JavaScript room for that :P And SomeKittens already hates it when I change my twitter name (prolly changes once a week lol)

Comment: Very much agree; perhaps a timed lock (1 day, 3 days, whatever) which is automatically released, or manually by a mod.

Comment: It sounds like your complaint "it skews the natural flow" is actually a claim that users of meta aren't representative of good SO users.  While I agree that meta activity isn't needed to be a good SO user, I don't think that metazens are skewing anything, just accelerating it.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "read only links?"  Are you asking that the links just not be clickable within the post?  Or are you asking for some other sort of behavior (regarding the linked post, for instance)?

Comment: @jadarnel27 I want it to look like a locked post would normally for instance.

Comment: I don't get why this is a problem. You post a question on Meta, you bring it to the community's attention. Then you...complain that it receives attention?

Comment: When I ask about my goats, I use fake goats… because it my real goat doesn't like to be petted? Wut?

Comment: @CodyGray often you want to bring a topic attention and the questions are _examples_. This is almost every other question in meta.

Comment: @RUJordan I 100% endorse goat gravatar.

Comment: related: [Impose a 24 hour voting freeze on questions being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: YES PLEASE.

It's not a huge deal, but when I see people post a Stack link in Meta, all I see is free advertisement that can yield reputation. If the question is taken to Meta for some sort of review, it should disable voting.

Of course, if they find the question good, they are more than welcome to find the link outside of the meta referral and vote for it. But blocking votes from Meta => Stack would discourage many advertised voting.

Comment: My only disagreement with your answer is where you said "*It's not a huge deal*", cause it kinda is.

Comment: Well, that depends on the person. Other peoples reputation gains don't phase me, so it's not a huge deal to me, then lol

Comment: @Dan but does it own many leather bound books?

Comment: @rlemon Yes, and it's apartment smells of rich mahogany.