# Add "What types of questions should I avoid answering?" to the Help Center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, help-center

I'm of the opinion that much of the problem we have on Stack Overflow with off-topic/poor questions is due to the abundance of quick answers to these questions.

My proposal is to add some sort of "What types of questions should I avoid answering?" section to the Help Center, and hopefully even automatically direct those who provide answers to bad questions to this page when a question they've answered gets closed.

The Help Center page could be as simple as:

> ### What Types of Questions should I avoid answering?
>
> Please avoid answering questions that are not a good fit for the site, such as questions that are:
>
> - [Off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
> - Too Broad
> - Unclear
> - Primarily Opinion-based
> - [Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)
>
> Providing answers to questions that are not a good fit for the site
>   encourages users to ask more questions that do not fit.
>
> Rather than answering these questions please consider the following
>   alternatives:
>
> - [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), if you think the question can be salvaged.
> - [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), to request clarification and additional details.
> - [Downvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), if you think the question does not show any research effort; if it is unclear or not useful.
> - [Flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) or [Vote to Close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) the question if it meets any of the existing close reasons.
>
> While we appreciate you taking the time to help out, and answer
>   questions, please keep in mind that in order to maintain a high
>   quality site with useful content we need to filter out some of the...
>   well, less useful content.
>
> Please see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
>   If it is a question that should not be asked, it is a question that should not be answered.

Obviously the wording could use some work, but you get the idea.

We seem to do an awful lot to discourage poor questions, but relatively little to discourage people from answering them. I think this approach may help to deter well meaning users from contributing to the poor question problem.

Comment: But answering bad questions is not going to get you banned from answering.  Providing bad answers will to any question.  So I'm not sure that sentence in your example would be appropriate.... unless of course that is part of your proposal.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Note the emphasis on "may eventually", in some situations these answers get downvoted to the point of leading to a ban. You may be right that its not the best wording, but I wanted to allude to potential consequences of answering bad questions.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Having a lot of deleted answers can get you answer banned.  Of course, most of your answers would need to be deleted/downvoted, and that simply happens quite rarely, mostly because answers like this actually get a lot of upvotes, and these types of questions aren't deleted in a sufficiently high percent of cases.

Comment: But who exactly is the target of that message? Newer users who would actually be able to be auto-blocked from answering for those downvotes probably wouldn't understand completely what makes a question "not a good fit" for our site. Users who do understand likely have enough reputation that they'd never need to worry about such a block.

Comment: @animuson Perhaps there's too much emphasis on the banning issue. I was more shooting for a "Please don't answer bad questions, and here's why..." I'm open to suggestions on rewording things to clear it up.

Comment: I think you should just drop that mention. Also, the article could probably benefit from some examples of situations where you might not want to answer (notably, if you included the phrase "my guess is" then you probably shouldn't be answering), or some quick guidelines on how to identify a question is bad and, if you don't think it is, how to fix it. The information currently presented seems like it could just be cut down and presented as an alert when a user attempts to answer a question with close votes or something.

Comment: @animuson I just struck it out... What I had in mind was something similar to [What types of questions should I avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) without simply reproducing all of that page with a different focus.

Comment: I can't find the reference anymore, but I recall there was a post somewhere talking about modifications to the post-ban to make it less of a hard stop and more of a speed bump.  Of course now that I am looking for it, I can't find it, but if it is true, you just might want to remove any references to a ban and focus on the answering bad questions in general.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I removed the bit about Answer bans, but I think the question ban part is reasonable. If you have an alternate wording feel free to post it in an answer. I know my version could use a lot of work.

Comment: Found the reference I was looking for.  Tim Post's answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230857/no-one-likes-quitting-cold-turkey/230899#230899) suggests that the post-ban was we know it might be on its way out.  It looks like there will still be something, but will be much different than it is now, so given that, maybe avoid mentioning the ban completely.

Comment: Aren't bad answers to bad questions downvoted anyway?  Why would you object to answering questions that are apparently answerable?  On another note, do people actually read these things?  Especially the ones who are exhibiting (apparently) bad behaviors?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I hadn't seen that one, thanks, I edited to address your concern.

Comment: @RobertHarvey bad answers to bad questions are downvoted but apparently not enough to discourage the behavior see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260084/1947286

Comment: Do you have any examples of questions that 1.  Should be closed, 2.  Were answered with upvotes on the answer, and 3.  Encouraged the OP or others to ask more bad questions?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It looks like many if not most closed questions have upvoted answers, even the [most heavily downvoted closed questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=6750&tab=votes&q=closed%3ayes) seem to draw answers that get upvoted. As far as proof that it encourages more bad questions, I suppose that is more of an educated guess... People are more likely to ask questions where they think they'll [get answered.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1662&tab=relevance&q=closed%3ayes%20answers%3a3)

Comment: Interesting... That's a fairly small subset.

Comment: @RobertHarvey 83,075 closed questions with more than 3 answers is a small subset? Perhaps when weighed against the total site traffic, but it hardly seems insignificant. Perhaps the [174,873 closed questions with accepted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+hasaccepted%3Ayes) is a little more relevant.

Comment: It's still only about 2.3 percent of all questions.

Comment: A mature person should be able to decide themselves what question to answer and what avoid. If there is a question there might be a right answer to it, even to "bad" and "poor" questions. Again, the definition of "bad" and "good" are vague.

Comment: I think the answer is to give points (maybe 2-3) for closing a question with a valid duplicate

Comment: Should we only asked the questions that are strictly bond to programming. I have posted the question and answer to a topic: analyse the code review and it contains terminal command also.

Answer (score 35):

I think you should put more of an emphasis on what an answer **should be** than what a question **shouldn't be**.  That way answerers can be more focused on their own contributions to the site, rather than judging the contributions of others.

So, instead of asking

**"What Types of Questions should I avoid answering"**

Ask

**"When should I avoid answering a question"**

They essentially mean the same thing, but the second version puts a little more emphasis on what's wrong with a potential answer than what's wrong with the question.

Most of the problem question types that you've posted about are problems because of the inability to post a sufficient answer to them.

- **Off-topic** Your answer will be off topic.
- **Too Broad** Your answer will either be too long or incomplete.
- **Unclear**  Since you don't really know the question, you don't know the answer.
- **Primarily Opinion-based** Your answer will be ambiguously incorrect
- **Duplicates** Not that big of a problem in the first place.

Comment: This line of thinking actually makes more sense than the whole *"we should prevent users from answering bad questions because that only encourages folks to ask more bad questions"* reasoning.

Comment: "Not that big of a problem in the first place" - do you mean the problem OP is having, posting a sufficient answer, or answering it is not that big of a problem? In any way, it might still encourage a lack-of-research mindset, but then again, so is pointing out the duplicate ... probably, so I don't really know ... but it definitely encourages duplication.

Comment: @Dukeling by "not that big of a problem in the first place"  I meant duplication itself is not a big problem

Comment: @SamIam Whether it's answering, commenting, finding / voting on the duplicate or simply reading it, dealing with duplicates take up time that could've been spent elsewhere - maybe answering some of those 1.7 million unanswered questions we've got, maybe doing some review, or maybe something else. And that's not to mention them filling up the search results when you're actually looking for something else.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm sure you've seen [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258087/1199226). Can you explain why you think that preventing answers to bad questions in order to discourage people from asking bad questions doesn't make (much) sense to you? For a lot of (most?) people, asking questions on SO is a means to an end. That end is solving the problem(s) they are currently facing, as quickly as possible. They have no intrinsic motivation to make sure they are contributing to the site in a way that is in line with its goals. [contd.]

Comment: If they always get what they want (i.e., answers that solve their problems), it is only logical that they will keep using the site in a way that is most convenient to *them*. Looking at it this way, denying them what they want would probably go a long way towards getting them to put more effort into their questions.

Comment: @itsjeyd: Well, first of all, if a question is answerable, I believe it should be answered.  Some questions are not answerable, and the "answers" they receive are horrendous.  But many questions are answerable, even though some of those questions are not of sufficient quality to act as a long-term reference resource.  They should be answered anyway.

Comment: I'm not talking about pandering to Help Vampires; if those folks can't make their questions answerable, then by all means don't bother to answer them.  Users who ask lots of bad questions get question-banned anyway.  Helpfullness first, folks; that's what we're here for, and that's what the site is supposed to be about.  I've said it before, and I'll say it again: *if you're looking at answers to find out why there are so many bad questions, you're looking at the wrong thing.*  Close and delete the questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for responding. I have a follow-up question: Why do *you* think there are so many bad questions?

Comment: @itsjeyd: Because people want what they want when they want it, they come from forum environments where anything goes, and they think it works the same way here.  The forum bias is very strong, despite the fact that forums are almost worthless as a means to get help.  I suspect that we get a lot of new users who are either very inexperienced and/or very young, who don't know yet what it means to be a professional; i.e. *have you done your homework first?*  Many of these folks haven't put in the work that's required to have a basic working knowledge of their craft.

Comment: Agree with Robert, and I would also add that there is no barrier to asking, so we get bad questions because it is easier to ask a question and get an answer hand-delivered than it is to wade through the thousands of Google results generated by people who also wanted answers hand-delivered.

Answer (score 13):

There's a kernel of something useful here; all too often, folks are doing what they think is appropriate - even helpful - only to be blindsided when the question is closed or deleted.

We should at least warn them about this.

So I've added a new section to [/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

[image: answer well-asked questions]

This is reasonably short and fits in well with the rest of the guidelines we provide to new answerers. I don't expect dramatic results, but every little bit helps.

As an aside... I'm getting really tired of this "War on Drugs" attitude toward folks writing answers to question here. That's *the primary activity here*; if you honestly believe the solution to the quality problem lies in discouraging folks from writing answers, then [you have a bright future fighting land wars in Asia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E1%BA%BFn_Tre).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how, but I'd like to see some change to point four to draw attention to the fact that most questions that are "too broad" don't actually result in attempted answers that are super long, but rather answers that are incomplete.

Comment: I also value having a guide on how to answer that isn't too long ("ain't nobody got time to read a manual!"), but it might also be useful to suggest to people looking to answer that they can also contribute by looking if the question is a duplicate, and flagging or voting to close as such.

Comment: See revision, Servy, @Cupcake

Comment: Who says you can't [win land wars in Asia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mongol_Empire_map.gif)?

Comment: After several years, I have come to the conclusion that the problem is technical rather than social. The solution to the quality problem is to make it so that the answers *can't* be written until the quality of the question is assured. After all, [there is no rush](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569). Questions should be closed *by default*. The comments should be used specifically to highlight potential problems that would be close reasons now, even as a chatroom; if/when everything is ironed out, open the question and automatically wipe any comments prior to the opening.

Answer (score -1):

With regards to duplicates, that means people answering questions, as well as those asking them, may need to do some research into the question to see if it has been asked before.

OFten those who mark a question as a duplicate will remember the original question and possibly replied to it, but it is not feasible for everyone who may answer to know if a question has been asked before.

Perhaps a time freeze between when a question is asked and when it can be answered to allow answerers time to do this research. Because as we all know, those who answer within 1-2 minutes of the question getting posted often get loads of rep.