# "Why shouldn't I answer off-topic questions?" FAQ

Tags: discussion, scope

Does anyone think it would be useful to have a FAQ on the subject of "Why shouldn't I answer off-topic questions?"  Anyone willing to write one?

I'm thinking I would post a link to it whenever I saw a blatantly off-topic question being answered (rather than, say, downvoting the answer).  Usually these are relatively new users, and at least some of them might respond well to a gentle approach.

(I considered writing one myself but I honestly don't know where to start.)

Comment: You mean something like this? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260087/add-what-types-of-questions-should-i-avoid-answering-to-the-help-center?lq=1

Comment: @DennisMeng: that's not really something I can link to, though it's obviously relevant.

Answer (score 16):

Answering off-topic questions, promotes the idea that these questions are acceptable questions to ask, thus leading to more off-topic questions.

If people didn't answer them, then people would know they would not get an answer and thus not have the incentive to ask them.

Answer (score 11):

**Answered off-topic questions make them seem OK and therefore fade into the depths** before attention is attracted to remedy the situation.

Questions are only closed because sufficient users see them to cast their close votes. While it's true that users may subscribe to tags and therefore sift through every post of a field where possible, few does and therefore the effectiveness *thru* this medium is very low.

As a result, users active in moderation mostly moderate from typical activity, for example, when looking for questions to answer. A low or even negative score question with no answers is an indication that the post has the potential to be answered by the user, or even voted to close where necessary.

Some users even only visit questions with no answers to try for a badge or two, such as **Enlightened**.

By having them answered, *this incentive is removed* and therefore *fewer users study the post*. This causes *less moderation hits*. It gets harder to be closed, and therefore when we bring the scale up to the entire [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) site, **more off-topic posts remain unclosed when they are answered.**

Additionally,

- Answered questions has higher barrier to cause eligibility for automatic deletion. As a result, **a higher proportion of these questions may have been deleted automatically due to fortune, but remain.**
- It gives out a signal that answering off-topic questions are OK. New users that sees the posts will therefore mimic their behavior and thus answer similar questions. This is a horrible cycle. We get therefore even more off-topic questions answered. <strike>Reputation falls into the wrong hands and [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is in dire.</strike> This is not good.

**Answering dilutes the effectiveness of closing.** By answering a question before it is put on hold, while it is true that the post may help another person, it **fundamentally contradicts with the feature of closing** and therefore make it less effective. As a result, less users vote to close (because it is not effective - someone else would just answer it, render putting it on hold rather pointless). The closing system will be weakened.

Plus, it makes you look bad for being a ["repwhore"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/3622940).