# How should I send help links to new users?

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, etiquette

There are a lot of questions by new users everyday, and they just get closed/downvoted and ignored. There are also those who have been on the site for years but never participated in anything besides asking one or two questions, and those might well write bad questions, too.

Then I composed a comment for those users, focusing mainly on the new ones, but I also post it to those others, sometimes. Sometimes I edit it, but I can't personalize a message for every case, because there are too many. The message should guide them to links that would teach them how to write a better question, so they would not get downvoted and would actually have their questions answered.

I know that those links may seem bothersome and sometimes sending them may be seem as rude or lazy, but they are actually there to help people, and they helped me a lot when I started in the community. Plus some of the questions I wouldn't know how to answer anyway, so I don't have any purpose other than trying to help.

This is the message:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! We would love to help you, but there are
>   some problems in the current format/content of your question that
>   makes it hard for some of us to help. If you haven't done so already,
>   please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How
>   do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
>   so it will be easier for us to help you.

But then I went back to some of the questions where I put this message to see if the user had edited the post, and if the comment was helpful, and I saw that my comment was just being deleted.

So I'm asking for opinions on what I should do and if anyone know why was it deleted, so I can write a better one.

Is the message rude? Unhelpful? Too long? Why where it deleted? Should I write a better one or should I just leave those questions alone?

Is there a better way to behave?

Comment: I don't consider it rude, unhelpful or too long (if posted on questions for which it is valid), but then I also think that you should just leave those kinds of questions alone, ideally after slapping them with a flag for closure...

Comment: It's not rude, but it is a little dismissive to just point to links and say "read this". If you can say there is something wrong with a post, then you can also give a clue what is wrong with it. Or even edit yourself.

Comment: @Gimby I agree, and I edit and sometimes I point out whats wrong, but sometimes it is too much too explain, or I just don't know what the user wanted. Examples: [Failed to build iso_img for android x86 build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540640/failed-to-build-iso-img-for-android-x86-build#comment103403116_58540640), [Error parsing JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58227031/error-parsing-json-file-c-users-abdul-wasay-desktop-app-app-json#comment102829153_58227031). (Comment was deleted in the first one, wasn't in the second).

Comment: Boilerplate comments are just that; boilerplate. Tailor your comments to explain exactly what's wrong with the question, or don't bother commenting at all.

Answer (score 7):

It is [not the first time I say this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372948/1426539), but I believe canned messages are generally not useful. Some mods apparently agree, and honour "no longer needed" flags on that kind of comment.

If you bother to post a comment under a post, **make the comment specific to that post**. Take the effort to address the particulars of the post you are commenting under.

If you are just providing links to the Help Centre, you'll be perceived as condescending by many—and simply as unhelpful by others.

Links to the Help Centre abound. And if the question is so bad as to merit a link to "How to Ask", in all probability, it should be closed. The "on-hold" banner already has more information than what you can provide in a canned comment, with the advantage of it being provided directly by the system, so there is less risk of entanglement in a non-productive comment thread.

And again, if what you really want is to help the user **before** the question gets closed, post a comment actually helping them: address specific problems with the post and make specific recommendations on how to fix them.

You are under no obligation to do so, of course; but that's the only way to actually provide help to such a user. The user has already seen links to the Help Centre by the time you post your comment, and it's likely they'll see more in the future.

Posting these links again doesn't do anything for them, unless you clearly spell out how they apply to their post, and what can they do to improve it (if it's possible at all).

As the saying goes, *"you can lead a horse to water..."*.

Comment: There is no argument on that it should be closed, neither that the "hold on" banner contains all this info already; the question is - have such comments any chance of getting the question improved *before* it gets closed?

Comment: I agree with most of it, usually with the canned message I leave a flag for closure and a downvote, and sometimes even point the specific problem. But is it really bad to leave the message even doing those stuff? The posts usually take long to actually get closed and give the newcomer the link, most of them will just leave the site feeling ignored and without knowing what they did wrong. Plus, if I just show the specifics of that post, they will make different mistakes in the future ones, because they didn't read stuff like "how to ask a question".

Comment: @desertnaut Canned messages directing users to the help centre? I would say they have very little chance of being useful, and greater chance of them not being well received.

Comment: I don't disagree; the question is *how little* (chance)? In *my* book, even for a chance in the order of ~ 5% of being helpful, I am taking it. This is all I'm saying - and arguably the same with OP here, who is currently wondering in above comment "*is it really bad?*". Well, is it?

Comment: One problem with "And if the question is so bad as to merit a link to "how to ask", in all probability it should be closed. The "on-hold" banner already has more information than what you can provide in a canned comment" in *low-traffic* tags is that the post may take days to be closed, if it ever is. In such a case, the OP may get no feedback at all as to why their question is being "ignored". So YMMV... FWIW I do agree that customized comments are better. In my experience with new users, there is a reaction, in some cases (not all).

Comment: anything's possible, it's certainly possible that one out of every few hundred cases get improved, however we have little ways of testing this and determining a conversion rate. I'd be willing to bet that if every question that ever received a close vote received one of those comments, the conversion rate would be *well* below 5%. (otherwise that would have already been automated)

Comment: Canned <> not specific.

Answer (score 4):

The comment you leave is not any more useful or likely to be followed by OP than the banner that is tagged on to the question when it’s closed.

Instead of leaving such a comment, vote to close (or flag if you don’t yet have the reputation for voting).

If you are committed to improving the question, leave a custom comment pointing out exactly how to improve the question. I like to add the `[edit]` markup to the comment, which turns into a link that will help OP edit their question (some don’t realize it’s possible to edit!).

But this take time and you can’t do it for all questions. This is what the close queue is for. Closing a bad or incomplete question before it is answered is the best thing that can happen to it. If OP decides to follow the guidelines, they’ll improve the question and it will be reopened.

Comment: re closing banner: indeed, but the idea is to provide some help/guidance *before* the question gets closed, thus giving a chance for possible improvements

Comment: @desertnaut: How many askers follow your advice based off these copy-paste comments and actually improve the question? Do you have any statistics that show that what you’re doing is useful? I think it’s not.

Comment: Well, I don't think you seriously expect from me to provide (or even keep) *statistics*, right? What I can say is that (very) occasionally such comments help (i.e. question gets improved, or migrated to the appropriate SE site, or even deleted *by the OP themselves*, hence moving workload out of the closing review queues), so what more should I ask for, really?

Comment: The links I choose (the tour and how to ask) are intended to teach them how to make questions in general, because pointing a specific problem will help them once, then they will make different mistakes in the next question and have it closed again. It's like the saying: "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime". Plus, most of the questions I see take long to get closed and give a useful guideline, while I usually post the message as soon as the newcomer asks the question. Is it really not useful?

Comment: @RicardoA. all our arguments here so far are actually just our opinions. No one can *assure* (I mean data & stats) that they are *not* helpful, but I have difficulty imagining someone arguing that they are actually *harmful*. So, since the Ultimate Directive (First, do no harm) is fulfilled, just follow your heart, play along, adapt & improvise according to the feedback you get, and *have fun*...

Comment: @Ricardo: In my experience, most users will simply ignore your comment. They’re hoping for an answer with as little effort as possible. The closing puts some pressure on reading up and improving the question. Users that do want to ask a good question have likely already taken the tour and read the “how to ask” page. It’s not trivial for everyone translating that to a good question. Pointing them at stuff they’ve already read is not useful. Pointing out specific things they can do to improve the question is useful.

Comment: @desertnaut: I don’t necessarily disagree with you, but I just think it’s best to put in your  curation efforts elsewhere.

Comment: I, too, don't disagree with anything in your last comment, save the "stuff they’ve already read" part. There's a vast percentage of new users coming here w/o bothering to go through the help center first (as they should). If my comments can help even a *tiny minority* of them to get things straight, then I am undertaking the effort (BTW, last week I had 2 posts voluntarily migrated to Cross Validated by the OPs after my comment; as it happened, they had never heard of CV...). That's all I'm saying (and I have abandoned other curation efforts, frustrated with the non-respect from some mods).

Answer (score 0):

For what it may worth, here is what *I* am doing (i.e. my copypasta list) for *new* users only, combining links with some short comment depending on the case, so that they are kinda more focused on specific issues of the respective posts:

> Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask
> about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that
> questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software
> library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.
>
> Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; your
> question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to
> Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I
> ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
>
> Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [How to
> Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a
> Minimal, Reproducible
> example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
>
> Welcome to SO; please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible
> example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as why [a wall
> of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).
>
> Welcome to SO; please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as
> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual
> question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)
>
> Welcome to SO; please post your code as *text* - see why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).
>
> Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; questions about machine learning theory & methodology are off-topic here, and should be posted at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.
>
> Kindly refrain from answering blatantly off-topic questions, as
> advised in the community guidelines - please see [Should one advise on
> off-topic
> questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions),
> [“Why shouldn't I answer off-topic questions?”
> FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262573/why-shouldnt-i-answer-off-topic-questions-faq),
> and [Should I answer off-topic
> questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)

AFAIK, these comments usually don't get deleted (at least not often); now, if you ask for any actual *impact* to new OP's, that's another story... But to be honest, *very* occasionally, the comment proves useful, i.e. the question gets improved, or migrated to the appropriate SE site, or even deleted *by the OP themselves*, hence moving workload off the closing review queues. I guess all three are positive outcomes, so what more could one ask for, really?

It should be clear that, at least IMO, voting for closure (or even downvoting) is not inconsistent with leaving such comments, and there are many cases where I do all 3 of them...

Comment: Note that the terminology has changed to "minimal, reproducible example": https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, rather than MCVE.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks, edited (here and in the original ;)

Comment: From what you've said, it sounds like you might find the following userscript helpful: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116) Basically, it allows you to have a list of comments which you can click on to add to posts.

Comment: Thanks @Makyen this is actually what I was looking for when I started reading this