# Asking for frameworks not ok, but answering with them is?

Tags: discussion

After posting a question on a Delphi problem I ran into. it was voted closed because of the way I phrased my questions:

> QUOTE: What would be my approach te realizing this? Are there any tools /
>   frameworks that can help me with this?

I learned from the comments, that its not appropriate to ask for frameworks in a StackOverflow question. To a certain degree I can understand that.

But what I find odd, is that it seems to be perfectly ok to mention frameworks in the answers to questions, often by the authors of the framework in question. I like those kind of answers because they help me learn about frameworks available and they can help me solve my programming problems.

Can anybody tell me why its not ok to ask for frameworks as solutions, but it is ok to provide them as solutions?

Comment: I downvote answers like this.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/programming-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: I downvote answers that mention a library/framework with no explanation of how to use it to solve the asker's problem, because moving from "How do I do X?" to "How do I do X _using library Y_?" is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not ok to answer off-topic questions. [Add "What types of questions should I avoid answering?" to the Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260087/add-what-types-of-questions-should-i-avoid-answering-to-the-help-center)

However the answers to off topic questions cannot necessarily be flagged as [Not an Answer (NAA)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) or low quality if they are providing links recommending tools, as they are indeed answering the question. whereas to questions not asking for recommendations, the link with a name will usually be rightfully flagged as NAA.

The problem with answering off topic questions (not including duplicates) is, the question is likely to be closed and deleted, which means any efforts made to answer such a question will ultimately be lost.

Comment: What does NAA mean?

Comment: It means Not An Answer

Comment: @Bascy sorry will edit to show and add links

Answer (score 5):

To add to @MsYvette's fine answer:

It is okay to answer a question with a library/framework, if you show how the library/framework can help in the OP's specific situation, preferrably with an example. For instance, if someone asks how to, say, filter undefined entries from an array in JavaScript, you can reply with the native `filter` method:

```
var noBad = arr.filter((item) => typeof item !== 'undefined');
```

but you can also mention the use of lodash's `compact` method:

```
var noBad = _.compact(arr);
```

The key is to demonstrate how the library/framework helps the user with their specific need, not just something like:

> Use https://lodash.com :)