# Is it acceptable to answer a relatively simple programming question (for less experienced)?

Tags: discussion

Let's say a relatively inexperienced user asks a question like

> I have problem XYZ (linking to documentaion about algorithm/ specification) and would like to know how to create this in code ?

Said user does not provide effort or specify language of choice, but the problem could be relevant to others, ie not specific to this user alone.

Many people here would simply flag as "no effort" and downvote user / close question.

Now my question: is it acceptable to make an exception, given that the problem is answered with relatively little effort - and supply user with an answer in a language of my choice ? Of course well documented.

Or, is it expected on higher-level users to always prefer the stricter line, to discourage people from not making an effort to learn before they make a question ?

**EDIT**  Thought example here was on replies to specific technical question (such as how to use linked documentation to make a calculation). Not some question that asked other's opinion or ask for a link list.  So it would actually be an answer that would provide a solution for someone, and others facing same problem. @gnat, I had to answer "no", it did not answer my question directly.

Comment: I do answer if it's not a like "search on google, click on the first result and copy paste" question.

Comment: There is no flag for "no effort"; this is expressed via voting.

Comment: Beginner questions about algorithms, relevant to other users as well as the OP, are very likely to be duplicates.

Comment: Not sure why I am downvoted massively on this, I tried to ask a legitimate question to try to follow official / unofficial guidelines. I agree with @Flash Thunder that responses should be made if it's not totally trivial.  

If I asked about somethint that's in an FAQ, please point to that and let me know if I did wrong. I can learn more from that than downvotes.

Comment: Voting is so different on Meta that the guideline explaining it it's name "What's meta?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta . and [Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/)

Comment: Now for you question, my take is that "no effort" is a missinterpretation of "Where is the code? Where are you failing?". On poor question their are often answered by op repeating the same requirement with caps and punctuation. Because many cannot be bothered  to try. When a community need those details to help.

Comment: And there is no evidence of of people not answering. In fact I can pigeon hole the exact opposite. Where high rep will answer, easy question that didn't had code. So if the question is: should we close the question?If it can't be fix yes! Should we answer? If you can fix the question, absolutly. If the question is fine and it's a dupe. Please don't.

Comment: @MyICQ 10 downvotes is [not massive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction).

Comment: "why I am downvoted massively on this" Read the [help] & FAQs & voting arrow mouseover texts. Where is your research on your question? Do you think this is not in help or a duplicate? And where is your research re that comment?

Comment: @Gimby That post is literally the most downvoted post in all of SO.Meta history [according to SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1389723/all-qs-as-scored-lower-than-x).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Comment: see also: [Add “What types of questions should I avoid answering?” to the Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260087/839601)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, it is perfectly fine to answer a "simple" question provided that your answer will help other people as well. After all, this is how the site works. Someone asks a question, no matter how easy or difficult, and other people write answers so that the same question doesn't need to be asked again in the future.

The problem with simple questions is that there's probably already an answer like that on Stack Overflow. In that case, just close as a duplicate.

There is no flag called "no effort". People should not close questions for lack of effort. The only effort that we require is to research if this problem hasn't been asked before and put effort into writing your question properly.

There is no way to "downvote user". In fact, we do not care who asked the question. It could be anonymous or a community wiki. We vote only based on the content. If the question is going to be useful to other people then upvote it, if it is not going to help anyone then downvote it.

Go on, answer any question you want as long as it is going to be a valuable contribution and a similar answer doesn't already exist on Stack Overflow yet.