# Is it okay to answer in anticipation of migration?

Tags: discussion, answers, migration

The reason I ask this is because [I just did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26482145/507674).

I believe the question is better suited for another SE website, but since I can provide an answer to it, I decided to do so.

Is this a bad thing? Should I close-vote as off-topic  and not answer?

Comment: "note that I can't get the correct site to appear..." - this is by design. The "belongs on another site" reason allows up to 5 other sites, and Webmasters is simply not one of them. If you want to migrate such questions you should use a custom-flag.

Comment: @Vogel612 Gotcha. Thanks for that.

Comment: related: [People who answer questions that are CLEARLY off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260083/839601)

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is a bad thing - especially if the target site isn't on the list of possible migration targets. Actually it's even a bad idea if the site is on the target list. This is because migration isn't guaranteed and you'll leave an off topic, answered question on Stack Overflow.

By answering you are encouraging the asking of off topic questions on Stack Overflow. It is very hard to tell someone that their question is off topic when they can point to other questions that have been answered and not migrated.

Comment: Oops. Understood! Thanks for letting me know :)